# retainCount always is -1?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, foundation, reference-counting

Can anyone help, i have some code and i am checking the retainCount but its always -1, it should be 1 at least?

here is my code, what am i doing wrong?

```
    NSNumber* n = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:100];

    NSLog(@"Count of   n : %i",[n retainCount]);

    NSNumber* n1 = n;

    NSLog(@"Count of   n : %i",[n retainCount]);
    NSLog(@"Count of   n1: %i",[n1 retainCount]);
    NSLog(@"Address of n : %p", n);
    NSLog(@"Address of n1: %p", n1);
```

The other strange thing i get is regarding the %i, saying that it actually returns a uint, so i replaced the %i to a %u and now i get a really long figure for the retainCount - 4294967295

A little confused, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://whentouseretaincount.com for some helpful suggestions on the use of `retainCount`.  Don't forget to scroll down :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result of `-retainCount` is worthless at your abstraction level, and this is another reason why.

…but to get on with your question: `NSUIntegerMax` indicates an immortal object.

You can find references to this in some documentation:

> You might override this method in a class to implement your own
>   reference-counting scheme. For objects that never get released (that
>   is, their release method does nothing), this method should return
>   UINT_MAX, as defined in `<limits.h>`.